# disabled 'hide' function in bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery-bootgrid

Im new to bootgrid and jquery or ajax. I found a good plugin for doing table(bootgrid), but I still cannot understand few code inside.
 Now I want to edit few thing in the droopdown at the top and right hand side, the drop down will show the `th` value,and when you click the value, the whole row of that value will be hide.
I just want to make one value of them become disabled.I dunwant user to hide the "Commands",because it row show the button.
The code was take form here: [Bootgrid](http://phpflow.com/php/addedit-delete-record-using-bootgrid-php-mysql/)

[image: I want to make the "commands" to disabled]

Comment: Please explain by what you mean by disabling one value. Plus, I feel that you mean that the action hide the entire column and not row.

Comment: I just dun want user can click the checkbox of `Commands`, if any idea please help me.Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. Let's suppose you have this **HTML** representing your bootgrid:

```
<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="ticket-id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">TICKET ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="submission-date">SUBMISSION DATE</th>
            <th data-column-id="status">STATUS</th>
            <th data-column-id="ownership">OWNERSHIP</th>
            <th data-column-id="applicant-name">APPLICANT NAME</th>
            <th data-column-id="applicant-ic">APPLICANT IC</th>
            <th data-column-id="order-type">ORDER TYPE</th>
            <th data-column-id="package">PACKAGE</th>
            <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands">Commands</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- data via javascript -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You just need to add `data-visible-in-selection="false"` to the column you don't want to be visible in that dropdown menu:

```
<th data-column-id="commands" data-visible-in-selection="false" data-formatter="commands">Commands</th>
```

Comment: thankyou! I thought this question will never have answer.Really appreciate of you answer!

Comment: Even the code still not working.But I think maybe is my problem, I will find out the solution

Comment: @QiuXue you're welcome. I'm going to prepare a JSFiddle so you can see this solution working, and you can also play around with it

Comment: I found out the problem already,that is because different version of plug in that I use.My plugin is direct get from here http://phpflow.com/php/addedit-delete-record-using-bootgrid-php-mysql/ .Yesterday I get an example from another website,and you code really work on that example.So my problem is only using wrong plugin.But I still need some time to do it.because I cant just replace the plugin,if I do that,my current bootgrid will going wrong

Comment: And very sorry about my broken english.Hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @QiuXue no problem, I could understand ;)